# Acumatica Report designer IF,AND, SUM formula

Tags: if-statement, sum, syntax-error, acumatica, report-designer

=IIf(
And(Sum($Basic_Salary) > 10000, Sum($Basic_Salary) < 80000),
Sum($Basic_Salary) * 0.04 / 2,
IIf(Sum($Basic_Salary) >= 80000, 3200 / 2, 400 / 2)
)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJCCU.png)
Im having trouble about this formula, thanks

I try to debug this formula, but I couldn't find the reason why im having the same issue.

Comment: And issue is, or trouble is? Formula isn't calculated? Or you have values in columns, and formula calculated them in a wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
=IIf( Sum($Basic_Salary) > 10000 AND Sum($Basic_Salary) < 80000, Sum($Basic_Salary) * 0.04 / 2, IIf(Sum($Basic_Salary) >= 80000, 3200 / 2, 400 / 2) )
```

And in this context is not a function.